# Drupal + LDAP + Automatic

Tags: drupal, authentication, ldap, automation

I've got [Drupal 6](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4583/building-an-intranet) setup within a XAMPP test area. I have LDAP authentication, groups and data working against Active Directory.

What I want... is since I'm on an intranet where users are logged in via user-names... is for automatic authentication, without the need to login via the website.

If it's more difficult than its worth, it's no major hassle, but I'd like to know if it's possible that when my users visit our intranet they auto-magically authenticate with their already logged in Windows session.

Ultimately, I may switch to IIS, but I do like having a portable, easy to backup/copy/test setup so for now I'm going to see if I can get this working in XAMPP.

Comment: Did you get an appropriate answer to your question or do you need something more?

Comment: Well in the 6 months since I posted the question, Drupal 7 has come out and LDAP API for it has been updated to something workable (ldap_integration works for drupal 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/ldap for Drupal 7
http://drupal.org/project/ldap_integration for Drupal 6

Both have done what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has provided a means for automatically passing authentication info if you're hosting with IIS - the [LDAP automatically login thread at Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/580718#comment-2611046) may be of interest.

Comment: Lemme add that, as of right now atleast, I'm working inside XAMPP - Apache, MySQL, PHP. Editing post.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://drupal.org/node/64230

(please note I didn't write that, it just came up in Google)